# how to remove duplicates in the table based on one column in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I do have a data like

## employee(id, transaction, sales)

```
id                  transaction             sales
1100000000002493644 46414104026581005688    2.2400
1100000000003120288 46403360812820035967    2.2400
1100000000002493644 46414104026581005688    2.2400
3300000000002592894 46427351011280903808    2.2400
1100000000108772072 46498465013410865589    3.9800
1100000000002493644 46498465013410865909    3.2900
```

As you can the above table has 3 columns. I'm trying to remove duplicates based on transaction data. I tried the below code, but it's not working

```
SELECT employee.*, DISTINCT(transaction) AS UNIQUE_TXN
FROM employee AS employee
INNER employee AS employee_1
    ON employee.transaction= employee_1.transaction
GROUP BY employee.*
```

But it's giving the wrong output. The expected output is below

```
id                  transaction             sales
1100000000002493644 46414104026581005688    2.2400
1100000000003120288 46403360812820035967    2.2400
3300000000002592894 46427351011280903808    2.2400
1100000000108772072 46498465013410865589    3.9800
1100000000002493644 46498465013410865909    3.2900
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, sample data like 1, 2, 3 is so much easier to get than 46498465013410865589, 46498465013410866589, 46498865013410865589.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find duplicates the following code could be used:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY transaction) AS num_per_transaction
FROM employee
QUALIFY num_per_transaction > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well a plain distinct query would seem to generate the result set you want here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, "transaction", sales
FROM employee;
```

But given that `sales` may be stored as a floating point, the above query may not work properly.  Instead, we can round `sales`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, "transaction", ROUND(sales, 2) AS sales
FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique transaction, you have to use group by function.
The query will look like:

```
SELECT employee.id, DISTINCT(employee.transaction) AS UNIQUE_TXN, employee.sales FROM employee AS employee GROUP BY employee.transaction;
```